# Dart xml parser doesn’t decode utf-8 characters

Tags: xml, utf-8, dart, flutter

I’ve used [http](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http) get method to get xml response and used [xml](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/xml) parser library.
But it doesn’t decode utf-8 characters.

```
http.get(URL).then((response) {
  final parsed = XmlDocument.parse(response.body);
  // Result is malformed
});
```

Comment: I suggest you supply (a) a sample XML document, and (b) an indication of how it is failing: what output or error messages does it produce?

Answer (score 3):

Dart uses UTF-16 for its strings. The xml library has no way of knowing that your data is encoded differently. Use the [Utf8Decoder](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.1/dart-convert/Utf8Decoder-class.html) from the [dart:convert](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.1/dart-convert/dart-convert-library.html) library to bring your data into the right format before trying to parse it.

```
import 'dart:convert' show utf8;

http.get(URL).then((response) {
  final utf16Body = utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes);
  final parsed = XmlDocument.parse(utf16Body);
  // ...
});
```